# Click event not responding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I'm working out of this [github](https://github.com/AutomaTom/lc_advLightningComp) project and I'm stuck here, when I click on the Schedule tab it does not do anything, what do I need to do to show the schedule component? as shown below in the print screen

App:

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute access="public" name="pageTabs" type="Object[]" 
       default="[{focus:'true', label:'Home', target:'c:lc_WelcomePageCmp'}, {label:'Schedule', target:'c:lc_SchedulePageCmp'}]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler name="navigateToPage" event="c:lc_NavigateToPageEvt" action="{!c.navigateToPage}"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="navigateToPage" type="c:lc_NavigateToPageEvt"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:lc_WelcomePageCmp" type="COMPONENT"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:lc_SchedulePageCmp" type="COMPONENT"/>
    <div class="slds">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread">
            <div class="slds-col slds-m-around--large">
                <img src="{!$Resource.lclogo}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-align-bottom ">
                <c:lc_PageTabListCmp pageTabs="{!v.pageTabs}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!v.body}
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

Component: lc_SchedulePageCmp

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute access="public" name="selectedEvents" type="Event[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <div class="slds-grid slds-theme--alt-inverse slds-p-around--large">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-truncate">Schedule</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-around--large">
        <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <p>We aim to bring you a broad spectrum of sessions across a multitude of subject areas. This list is constantly being updated so please check back regularly to see what other amazing sessions we have arranged for you.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one you might try uncommenting it?

AFAIS, the only occurence of lc_SchedulePageCmp is in your app, on the second dependency. And those two dependencies have been commented out.

Also, why not just call the component as how you do in the component itself with the somethingPage component? i.e. `<c:lc_SchedulePageCmp attr="value" />`
(I'm completely unfamiliar with aura:dependencies, so I might be swearing here, in which case my apologies :) )

Comment: it was typo and i have un-comment in the question.

Comment: Ah, then I have no idea. I see on your github page it's a trailhead module which I haven't done (yet), so then I'm afraid I can't help you any further... Best of luck though!